# Awk equivalent in PowerShell to apply to console outputted table

Tags: powershell, command-line

I've looked at many solutions online, but none relate to my specific situation. I have following PowerShell command output:

```
    PS C:\Users\Administrator> Query User | Select-String "rdp"

>administrator         rdp-tcp#7           2  Active          .  4/28/2022 10:22 AM
```

If I were using bash, it would be a simple case of using awk to select the 2nd column (which is the one I require).

Can anyone help me with how I would achieve the same result in PowerShell?

Comment: Why not use [PSTerminalServices](https://github.com/imseandavis/PSTerminalServices) module instead?

Comment: You can also use this [Function: `Get-QUser`](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/5014-get-quser) built as a wrapper around `QUser.exe` to turn it into objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just use `$ENV:SESSIONNAME` to get that string.

If you want to play with a bit of code to "emulate" awk, you can use

```
((Query User) -match 'rdp' -split '\s+')[1]
```

Note:

- `(Query User)` - The string returned by `Query User`...
- `... -match 'rdp'` - is first matched with `rdp`, and once the match is obtained,
- `... -split '\s+'` - it is split with one or more whitespaces.
- `(...)[1]` - Then, the second item is returned using indexing, `[1]` (since array indices are zero-based).

Answer (score 0):

[Wiktor Stribiżew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72043594/45375) provides an effective solution for a *single* matching line (which may be all that is needed in this case).

To generalize and **elaborate on the [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) angle**:

- If fields need to be extracted from *multiple* lines, you need *multiple* calls to the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator.

  - It is the *unary* form, of `-split`, as used below, that behaves AWK-like with respect to field splitting, in that any nonempty run of whitespace separates fields, with leading and trailing whitespace getting ignored.
- For processing multiple lines one by one, you can use the [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement, which is AWK-inspired too.

The equivalent of this AWK command, which extracts the 2nd field from each line containing the string "rdp":

```sh
query user | awk '/rdp/ { print $2 }'
```

is this `switch` statement:

```sh
switch -Regex (query user) { 'rdp' { (-split $_)[1] } }
```

Note:

- `0`-based *array* indexing applies in PowerShell, because the `-split` operator returns an array of tokens; by contrast, AWK's field numbering start with `$1` (`$0` representing the whole line). That is, field `$2` in AWK corresponds to array index `1` in PowerShell.
- Add `-CaseSensitive` if needed; PowerShell is case-INsensitive by default.

---

**Optional reading: `grep` vs. `Select-String`**:

Another Unix-utility solution option is to use [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep), as follows:

```sh
query user | grep -Eo '\brdp[^ ]+'
```

PowerShell's `grep` analog is [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string).

As of PowerShell 7.2.2, there is a pending, green-lighted *future improvement* to `Select-String` that would allow returning just the matched part of matching lines, analogous to `grep`'s `-o`; community members are welcome to implement it - see [GitHub issue #7712](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7712).

```sh
# FUTURE improvement.
query user | Select-String -OnlyMatching '\brdp[^ ]+'
```

For now, a more verbose solution is required:

```sh
query user | Select-String '\brdp[^ ]+' | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```